# aptik for non-root users

Tags: backup

I want non-root users to be able to use `aptik`, particularly those with encrypted home directrories. I tried modifying the `sudoers` file for them -- it did not work.

Here is the entry I set up in the `sudoer` file for `mxp`, a normal user.

---

```
Cmnd_Alias CRYPT = /usr/bin/truecrypt

Cmnd_Alias APTIK = /usr/bin/aptik

Cmnd_Alias FSARCH = /usr/sbin/fsarchiver

Cmnd_Alias DAR   = /usr/bin/dar

Cmnd_Alias BLKID = /sbin/blkid

Cmnd_Alias FUSE  = /usr/bin/Gmount-iso

Cmnd_Alias USBDEV  = /usr/bin/unetbootin

Cmnd_Alias ADMCMDS = CRYPT,USBDEV,BLKID,FUSE,DAR,FSARCH,APTIK



mxp ALL=(root)NOPASSWD:ADMCMDS
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating aliases you should  run `source ~/.bashrc` in terminal to make the changes.

Also it is `mxp ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: ADMCMDS`

There is *space* between (root) and NOPASSWD & between : and ADMCMDS

Comment: That's interesting. mxp can actually use all of the commands in ADMCMDS, except aptik